# Month and Year date conversion

Tags: php, datetime, laravel-5, authorize.net

I have a Credit card expiry date with month and year only coming in form of a string say `08/17`, How can I change this string in a format so that I can pass it to `Authorize.net`

```
$creditCard->setExpirationDate( "2017-08");
```

I have tried to use `strtotime()` but it is giving me the current year

```
echo $date = date('Y-m', strtotime($ccInfo['exp_date']));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should use `date_create_from_format` instead of `strtotime` to build your date:

```
echo date_create_from_format('m/y', '08/17')->format('Y-m');
```

The function creates a `\DateTime` object, so you can call format to get the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

You can also write like this

```
$eventDate = DateTime::createFromFormat('m/y', '08/17');
echo date_format($eventDate, 'Y-m');
```